# saving a numpy array as a io.BytesIO with jpg format

Tags: python, excel, opencv, numpy

#### I am using xlsxwriter to insert image into excel in python code.

Now, I had image data(numpy array) after opencv process. I would like insert this image data to excel. But xlswriter only support io.BytesIO stream.

question: I don't know how to convert numpy array to [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) with jpg format.

I have trying numpy.tostring but without jpg format.

the code working well in below:

`_f = open('test.jpg') # I would like to insert test.jpg
worksheet.insert_image('E2', 'abc.jpg', {'image_data': _f.read()})`

Anybody can help me ? thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't `jpeg` format specialized, using diagonal scanning and compression?  If so that will require a custom `jpeg` converter (possibly licensed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`cv2.imencode`](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/70396/cv2.imencode) function to convert a `numpy` array to `jpg` format.

Answer (score 9):

Convert the numpy arrays to PIL Image structure, then use BytesIO to store the encoded image.

```
img_crop_pil = Image.fromarray(numpy_image)
byte_io = BytesIO()
img_crop_pil.save(byte_io, format="JPG")
jpg_buffer = byte_io.getvalue()
byte_io.close()
```

Comment: dzieki, Radek ;)